# Updating woocommerce product name through mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to bulk update 300+ products using the following mysql statement for each product:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_title` = 'Updated Product Name' WHERE `post_type` = 'product' AND `post_status` = 'publish' AND `id` = 'xxxxx';
```

However, when I go in to edit the product in the admin panel, the `post_title` field still has the old value and the product category pages still have the old value. Each product page does display the new value though.

The site is running Woocommerce version 3.4.3

Comment: The data is cached as transients to be cleared I suppose, so that's why? So try to go in backend > Woocommerce > Status > Tools (tab) and in "WooCommerce transients" line click on "Clear transcients". If it doesn't work you will have to seach in wp_otions table to find and delete the guilty.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried clearing transients but they still aren't updating. (There wasn't anything matching the updated products in the wp_options table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site was using Redis caching; clearing the cache solved the issue.